# XMLHttpRequest download with File Name Included (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to include two functions in this download script but I can not get it to work

1- At the end of the download (animated download bar) start the download automatically in the Sample browser: `window.open ()`.
but that includes the default name, in the script.

2- When detecting a dead link or with 0 bytes in size,`request.open ()` throw a warning if possible.

any help will be very useful, Regards.

```js
var _OBJECT_URL;


document.querySelector('#download-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
     if(request.readyState == 2 && request.status == 200) {
      document.querySelector('#start-download').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#download-button').style.display = 'none';
     }
     else if(request.readyState == 3) {
      document.querySelector('#download-progress-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#start-download').style.display = 'none';
     }
     else if(request.readyState == 4) {





      _OBJECT_URL =  URL.createObjectURL(request.response);



document.querySelector('#save-file').setAttribute('href', _OBJECT_URL);

// NAME default 
document.querySelector('#save-file').setAttribute('download', 'MyNameFile.zp');
      // OPEN FILE IN BROWSER

//Open file, start download automatically sample: window.open(_OBJECT_URL)
// and that includes the default name "MyFilename.zip"

    

     


document.querySelector('#save-file').style.display = 'block';







      document.querySelector('#download-progress-container').style.display = 'none';

      setTimeout(function() {
       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);

       document.querySelector('#download-button').style.display = 'block';
       document.querySelector('#save-file').style.display = 'none';
      }, 60*1000);
     }
    });
    request.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
     var percent_complete = (e.loaded / e.total)*100;
     document.querySelector('#download-progress').style.width = percent_complete + '%';
    });


    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.open('get', 'https://www.google.com.sv/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'); 
    request.send(); 


// HERE NOTICE DEAD LINK

//If the link is dead, notify with some notice


});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "Titillium Web";
 font-size: 15px;
}

#demo-container {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 60px auto;
}

#download-button {
 background-color: white;
 color: #2980b9;
 border: 2px solid #2980b9;
 font-family: inherit;
 outline: none;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: inherit;
 border-radius: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#start-download {
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
}

#download-progress-container {
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 4px;
 display: none;
 height: 20px;
}

#download-progress {
 background-color: #2980b9;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
}

#save-file {
 color: #2980b9;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: none;
 text-align: center;
}

#save-file:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="demo-container">
 <button id="download-button">Download</button>
 <div id="download-ui-container">
  <div id="start-download">Starting Download..</div>
  <div id="download-progress-container"><div id="download-progress"></div></div>
  <a  id="save-file">Save File</a>




 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: place the Javascript format but make errors

Comment: hello I could correct the entry, can you help me please?